# Is it possible to change default orientation of browsing cube built using 3D Juump API?

Tags: angular, typescript, 3d, orientation

I am trying to change the default orientation of browsing cube built using 3D Juump API. Currently, in the initial load, the back side of the cube is selected by default. Is there any way to modify this default selection?